# How to load image from src/images folder rather than from assets folder in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm new to Angular 2. I'm generating angular 2 project by angular cli. If i'm keeping my image within `src/images` folder, its showing 404 file not found in browser where as its displaying image if its in `src/assets` folder.

**What is the reason behind it and how to load an image from src/images folder..??**

```html
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Welcome to {{title}}!
  </h1>
  <img width="300" src="./images/img.jpg">
</div>
```

[browser output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIJ8z.jpg) link for my output

[code snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Et6vP.jpg) source code snap

Answer (score 2):

The `angular-cli` generated `.angular-cli.json` where you can found the project configuration, you use the assets array in .angular-cli.json to list files or folders you want to copy as-is when building your project.

[image: .angular-cli.json]

Put your files inside of `assets` and use:

```
<img width="300" src="/assets/images/img.jpg">
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. But my query is without putting in assets folder, is there any other way to access src/images/img.jpg.

Comment: Why you want to do this?

Comment: its my project requirement and I have seen samples where image is in src/images folder. But for me its not working. I dont know why.

Answer (score 1):

Updated latest answer :

follow below steps :

my images located in src => images => 1.png it means located in outside the assets folder

**.angular-cli.json**

open angular-cli.json file find the assets array add inside the array your folder name like images.

```
"assets": [
  "assets",
  "images",
  "favicon.ico"
],
```

**componenet.html**

```
<img src="images/1.png">
```

Comment: Yes, <img src="assets/images/a1.jpg"> works fine always. But for <img src="src/images/a1.jpg"> is not the correct solution.

Comment: @Prava - both are working correctly for me and see the output images recently updated in my ans.

Comment: I used <img src="src/images/img.jpg"> I'm not getting that <img> tag in console, coz of same 404 error.

Comment: If you use webpack only then <img src="src/images/img.jpg"> will work else it won't.

Comment: use this commands to add webpack to your project . 1. ng eject, 2. npm install

Comment: R u saying me to build my project first, then to run..??

Comment: I have used 1. ng eject, 2. npm install, now what shall i do

Comment: run your project check the image file path correctly if it's correct then run the project and this might work

Comment: here is my sample exmaple github here my sample example https://github.com/csomethingr/angularFullStack.git. clone it install npm then run the project in localhost:4200